# How do I assign keys to every character in a string?

Tags: python, string, dictionary

This is what I was told to do, "Write a python grogram that asks the user for a string, then create the following dictionary: The values are the letters in the string, with the corresponding key being the place in the string. For example if the user entered the string “CSC120” then  create the dictionary D.
D = {‘C’:0, ‘S’:1, ‘C’:2, ‘1’:3, ‘2’:4, ‘0’:5 }"

This is my code so far:

```
usr = input('enter string here')
result = ''
for ch in usr:
    result = result + ch + ' '
print(result[:-1]) #value

key = 0
while (key < len(usr)):
    key = key +1    #key
print(key)

dict = {key: result}
print(dict)
```

And this is the output:
    enter string here csc120

```
c s c 1 2 0

6

{6: 'c s c 1 2 0 }
```

This is from an online tutorial so I can't really ask a professor for help and I'm new to python / programming and appreciate all the help I can get!

I just don't understand how to assign the key to every character in the string so that it looks like this:
D = {'C':0, 'S':1 etc...}

Comment: I don't know who gave you this assignment, but the dictionary `D = {‘C’:0, ‘S’:1, ‘C’:2, ‘1’:3, ‘2’:4, ‘0’:5 }` cannot exist in python because the key `C` is repeated -- and dictionaries cannot have repeated keys ...

Comment: The example dictionary you have uses values as key, and position as value.  You need to reverse that

Comment: the explanation and the example are contradictory. Going with the explanation, a trivial answer is `dict(enumerate(usr))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate() to iterate over each letter with an index and then create a dict from it:

```
In [1]: s = "CSC120"
In [2]: dict(enumerate(s))
Out[2]: {0: 'C', 1: 'S', 2: 'C', 3: '1', 4: '2', 5: '0'}
```

(This is a dictionary where the values are the letters in the string, with the corresponding key being the place in the string - your example has it the other way round)

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use a generator expression than a list comprehension.